# How to find which object we are touching using tapgesture

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have so many UIview objects on self.view and one tap gesture is also available on self.view. Now my concern is when ever i touch the self.view i would like to know under my touch any UIView object is there or not if s i want to get the properties of that object like tag value. Please help me how to get information.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]`

Comment: Hi xlc thanks a lot. Can u elaborate .... by giving a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to read my book on this topic:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_hit_testing

Example code from that section:

```
CGPoint p = [g locationOfTouch:0 inView:self]; // g is the gesture recognizer
UIView* v = [self hitTest:p withEvent:nil];
```

Where `self` is the superview to which the gesture recognizer is attached. You'll need to make the necessary substitutions...